# Bi-Directional Communication using C# TCP Channels

Tags: c#, networking, tcp, remoting, genuinechannels

Is there a native way to implement the features provided by the Genuine Channels (http://www.genuinechannels.com) component? Essentially, it provides the same features as the .net remoting component, with the only difference being .net remoting is unidirectional. I am looking for something where, as a client, I could connect to a server, and then pass messages to the server, and then have the server be able to pass messages to the client (whenever the server wanted, without the client calling a function).

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

WCF has bydirectional surport over TCP as standard.

(When WCF does bydirectional channels over TCP, a message from one end can block a message from the other end.    This is due to the fact that WCF bydirectional channels just allows both ends to send messages, it does not create two independent channels over a single TCP socket.)

However WCF does not have bydirectional surport over a **single** HTTP connection, and the [WCF bydirectional HTTP surport does not cope with firewalls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700917/how-does-a-wcf-server-inform-a-wcf-client-about-changes-better-solution-then-si).

Answer (score 1):

You'll either have to switch roles of the client and server (i.e. who is listening and who writes) or you can open a second socket on the same port to provide your client's server. Your client's server is the thing that would listen for messages from what you call the server, and then [raise events|queue|process] the messages it receives.